# youtube gdata upload videos php

Tags: php, gdata

I am working on an application where I need to fetch all the videos from a particular account using youtube gdata api. my question is regarding uploading videos. the gdata youtube api examples for uploading videos redirects me to the youtube.com for authentication.

Is this possible not to redirect user to the youtube and upload videos from my website ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.I Managed to solve this. For having this we need to use client side authentication, which is usually not recommended by the youtube gdata apis. But we can use the client side authentication for this. If any body else is getting the same problem/specs then please go for the term **Client side Authentication** in the gdata youtube apis.